# Recording with autotune with SoundCraft Si Compact 32 audio mixer?

Tags: mixing

Our local church just got a new SoundCraft Si Compact 32 mixer. We really want to record a CD, but the vocalists are demanding autotune. Is it possible to get autotune to work with this mixer, or do I have to record the vocals separately, and add autotune on a DAW on the computer? If it is possible to record all 32 channels of the mixer directly to the computer, then that would be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some autotune devices that will autotune live, they are much more expensive than a DAW on a computer running autotune on the recording.

The mixer is pretty much irrelevant, however if you are wanting to autotune live, you will need as many autotunes as channels you wish to autotune - could be expensive. With a DAW, you can just run it for each channel asynchronously as you need.

Alternatively - get them to sing in tune.

Comment: Yes, so there are no way of having an auto tune effect, like you have reverb and delay as lexicon effects?

Comment: No - you **can** autotune live. It will just be expensive. If you have a multichannel autotuner get it in the effects loop at the mixer. Otherwise you will need one on each mic channel.

Comment: I had a small hope since the mixer was digital..

Answer (score 1):

It would be cheaper and give a better result (and take more time) if you auto tune in the computer later. Doing this would require that your mixer has direct outs on each channel and your computers interface has 32 inputs.

This would require a bit of an investment in hardware, but would still be cheaper then 32 rackmount autotune devices. If you want, I'll help explain what setting that up would take.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do it. I unfortunately don't have the money to spend on a super-computer and a couple of 16x16 audio interfaces... I just wondered if it was possible to have Auto Tune directly inside the mixer, since it was digital.. The first digital mixer I ever tried. But there are only LEX effects.

Comment: Shoot, I totally missed that it was a digital mixer. Still even if there is an auto tune like plugin for it, it's going to b hard to run a ton of them at once and not have it sound like a T-Pain song. Maybe you should try the old school, slightly pitch-shifted delay/reverb trick.

Comment: The Old School trick? I haven't heard about that one?

Comment: Send everything to a hall reverb. Pitch one side of the reverb return up about fifteen cents, with a bit of modulation on the pitch shift. Do the same on the other side, but pitch it down. Muck with those setting a bit till it creates a bit of a 'blur' around the pitch. This can create either a pleasing tone that hides minor pitch problems or sound like crap, trust your ears.